# How to extract parameters from PySpark reading process?

Tags: pyspark

I am reading data (csv format) with PySpark in this way:

```
spark.read.format('csv').option('header', 'true').load(my_path)
```

where `my_path` it is something like:

```
s3://my_root/my_datasource/2012-01-01/
s3://my_root/my_datasource/2012-01-02/
s3://my_root/my_datasource/2012-01-03/
s3://my_root/my_datasource/2012-01-04/
...
s3://my_root/my_datasource/<until today>/
```

as you can see there are different buckets per single day `YYYY-MM-DD`.
If I read the data above with:

```
spark.read.format('csv').option('header', 'true').load('s3://my_root/my_datasource')
```

I will be able to process the whole data. However when I do that, how can I extract the information for the relative date (`2012-01-01`, `2012-01-02`, etc) as it is not present in the data itself but only as folder name?

Comment: Only that date that needs to be attached as column to the Dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`regexp_extract`** function and the matching regular expression `"(\\d{4}\-\\d{2}\-\\d{2})"` to capture date part.

To get the folder path use **`input_file_name()`** function in spark.

**`Example`**:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

#creating sample dataframe
df=spark.createDataFrame([('s3://my_root/my_datasource/2012-01-01/',),('s3://my_root/my_datasource/2012-01-02/',)],['folder_path'])
#use input_file_name() function
df = df.withColumn("input_folder_path", input_file_name())
df1 = df.withColumn("dt", regexp_extract(col("folder_path"),"(\\d{4}\-\\d{2}\-\\d{2})",1))

df1.show(10,False)
#+--------------------------------------+----------+
#|folder_path                           |dt        |
#+--------------------------------------+----------+
#|s3://my_root/my_datasource/2012-01-01/|2012-01-01|
#|s3://my_root/my_datasource/2012-01-02/|2012-01-02|
#+--------------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Please read the answer better! use `df.withColumn("input_folder_path", input_file_name())`
then you will get the path as new column and then use the `input_folder_path` to extract date from the `path`

Comment: I wasn't aware of that function, thank you!